What is the lowest placed team to have a Golden Boot winner?
At the time of writing, in the 2023/24 Premier League season, Cole Palmer of Chelsea is currently joint-top of the goal scoring charts with 20 goals, with Chelsea currently 9th in the Premier League table.
Normally the top goal scorer in a season is from one of the top few teams, if not the overall winners.
What is the lowest-placed team to contain the Golden Boot winner in a Premier League season?

That would be Coventry City in the 1997-98 season. They finished 11th, but striker Dion Dublin won the Golden Boot (jointly with Michael Owen and Chris Sutton) with 18 goals.
Honourable mentions:

In the 1992-93 season, Teddy Sheringham won the Golden Boot with 22 goals: 1 goal for Nottingham Forest (who finished dead last), and 21 goals for Tottenham (who finished 8th). I'm not counting Nottingham Forest because I feel like that would violate the spirit of the question, but it's worth mentioning.
In the 2004-05 season, Andy Johnson came second in the Golden Boot race behind Thierry Henry, having scored 21 goals for Crystal Palace (who finished 18th - Johnson single-handedly scored over half of their goals).
If you go back to the old First Division era, then the record is held by Southampton: they finished 20th in 1973-74 and were relegated, but striker  Mick Channon was the league's top scorer with 21 goals.

